# Will updating my Xcode to latest version delete my previously installed SDKs?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, version, updates

I'm new to MAC, I recently updated my Xcode to 7.2. Will this update have SDKs for iOS versions prior to 9.2?

I mean will SDKs for iOS 7.1,8.2,etc be available on my machine even after the update or should I download them separately?

Comment: If you want means you need to download.If you update means only latest version i.e.,7.2 is available

Answer (score 2):

You only got the newest iOS - 9.2, but u can download the older iOS simulator and other kinds of devices in Preference - Download tab